# Custom Font not working in Fragment Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I wanted to make a custom font textview.

I've got in **FragEarnCredits.java:**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (aiView == null) {
            aiView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_earn_credits, container, false);
        }


        t = (TextView) aiView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        Typeface myCustomFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(aiContext.getAssets(),"fonts/bebas.otf");
        t.setTypeface(myCustomFont);
```

In **fragment_earn_credits.xml**:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:text="Fashion Wallet"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textColor="@color/md_brown_700"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  />
```

And I'm getting null error. Why? Please help me guys!

**#EDIT**

I tried to change:

```
 Typeface myCustomFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(aiContext.getAssets(),"fonts/bebas.otf");
```

to

```
Typeface myCustomFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/bebas.otf");
```

And 0 errors but there is not changing font.

Answer (score 0):

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/customfont.ttf");
```

The context you are sending in the fragment class, you have to use your actual context.

Hope it helps! Cheers!

Comment: not working @aaoo. 0 errors, and the font is not changed

Comment: @FootballFan, can u try with another font to see if the font file is okay?

Comment: Can I see a screenshot of your folder structure in android studio? @FootballFan